# Changing the default marker to a specific image on google maps API

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

what this code does is, when a user inputs **two cordinates**, it setup the map with a **two markers** and a line to show the **direction**. Is it possible to change the d**efault marker** to a **specific image** differently for both cordinate, lets say i want the first cordinate to represent "**image1.jpeg**" and second cordinate to represent "**image2.jpeg**".

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Animations</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
    //  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.12, -3.2);                   //center of the map
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat?>, <?php echo $_Mylon?>);
      var a = [
         new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat?>, <?php echo $_Mylon?>),
         new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat2?>, <?php echo $_Mylon2?>)
        ];
      var marker;
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: center
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);

    for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          draggable:true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: a[i]
      });

    }   
     var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat?>, <?php echo $_Mylon?>),
            new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat2?>, <?php echo $_Mylon2?>)
        ];

       var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);

      }


    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">map div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where in this code can i change the marker to my specific image, thanks

Comment: There is a load of information on custom markers in [the google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to do an `IF` statement to determine which image the marker should load.

```
if(i == 0) iconImage = "image1.jpeg";
else if(i == 1)  iconImage = "image2.jpeg";
```

Then simply add the custom icon and variable to the marker:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          draggable:true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: a[i],
          icon: iconImage
});
```

Comment: with this process, it only shows an image for both cordinates, i want it to show different image, thanks

Comment: Did you add an `if statement` ?

Comment: where do i add the if statement, is it just befopre the variable to the marker??